# How do I use a separate C# file on one xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making an AI in **WPF** and i want to use a separate **C#** file for the AI. When I type `start();` in one file I want it to find it from the other file and use it, and when I type `myImage.visibilty = visibility.hidden` so that it will hide the image from the `xaml` from the original c# file.

Here is my second **C#** file

```
    using System.Windows;


namespace Hexapawn
{
    public class AI2 : MainWindow
    {

        public AI2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //somecode
        }

        public void start()
        {
            //somecode
        }



    }
}
```

I have tried 
`using myproject.Myfile;`,
`using myFile;`
but it isn't able to use methods from the other file or change the `xaml`.

Comment: Monolitic code is really a bad idea, because it will be really hard to modify later, you should consider separating your presentation logic and your business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a partial class. Your main window class is already a partial class. You can declare 1 more partial class of the same class in a separate file and use all the methods from it in your first class.

However, your `AI2` class seems more like a Model to me which will deal with non-UI business logic. You can implement the [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) which is more suited for WPF-based applications and make your new `AI2` class as the Model of MVVM.